# FFmpeg droplet on Windows (converting EXR sequences to mp4)

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a little droplet on my desktop in windows10 that creates mp4 files out of exr sequences. My idea would be to drag the first frame of the sequence and the droplet would recognize the sequence and cook a nice mp4 video out of it.

My source sequence usually look like this:
render.0001.exr
render.0002.exr
render.0003.exr
etc.

So far I'm doing this completely manually by typing this to a command line:

```
ffmpeg.exe -gamma 2.2 -i render.%04d.exr -q:v 0 -r 25 video.mp4
```

This command creates a nice quality gamma 2.2 mp4 which is perfect but manually setting it is obviously a hassle.

After a little google-ing I've found this droplet:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i %1 -y %~n1_preview.mp4
```

Which is brilliant but doesn't recognize file sequences so if I drop multiple files on it it will create single frame mp4 files. I guess it is missing the %04d but I have no idea where to put it or whether it needs some other parameter to work properly.

Do you guys and girls have any idea how to format this droplet properly? It would be a huge timesaver.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: anyone? please? :)